# CSS/Jscript height problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a grid of squares which updates with the size of the window. I am currently using the following js code to do this:

```
$(window).ready(updateHeight);
$(window).resize(updateHeight);

function updateHeight() {
    var div = $('.grid');
    var width = div.width();;
    div.css('height', width);

    var ratio=14.3/126;
    div = $('.face');
    width = div.width();;
    div.css('height', width+(ratio*width));

    ratio=30.5/15;
    div = $('.cubie');
    width = div.width();;
    div.css('height', width+(ratio*width));
};
```

The cubies are nested inside faces, which are nested inside the grid in my html. First i tried setting the height with

```
div.css('height', width)
```

..but for some reason that didn't make my faces and cubies square. The ratio thing helps correct it on my screen size, but the smaller i make the window the more noticeable the error becomes, so I'm searching for a different solution right now, and i cant seem to find one. Help appreciated.

PS: if it matters, the .grid width is 50% of the body, the .face are 20% of the .grid, and the .cubie are ~33% of that.

Comment: forgot your html?